# PHP MySql update() with array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my database with the help of array,how it will be right to write the code?

Here is my code but it gives error smth about MySql server version.

```
 public function update($fields, $values, $id) {
        $implodeFieldsArray = implode( ',', $fields );
        $implodeValuesArray = '"'.implode( '","', $values ).'"';
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE $this->tabname ('.$implodeFieldsArray.') WHERE id=$id VALUES ('.$implodeValuesArray.')');
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '->tabname (title,post) WHERE id=$id VALUES ("done","done")' at line 1' in D:\OpenServer\domains\mvc.dev\models\database.php:51 Stack trace: #0 D:\OpenServer\domains\mvc.dev\models\database.php(51): PDOStatement->execute() #1 D:\OpenServer\domains\mvc.dev\views\profile.php(47): DatabaseEdit->updateNew(Array, Array, NULL) #2 {main} thrown in

Comment: you cannot use this syntax, that the syntax for insert into

Comment: What syntax should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mysql docs this is the correct syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

Your code will become:

```
public function update($fields, $values, $id) {
    $update = "";
    $update = "";
    for ($i=0;$i<count($fields)-1;$i++){
      $update .= $fields[$i]."='".$values[$i]."',";
    }
    $update .= $fields[$i]."='".$values[$i]."'";
    $sql = 'UPDATE '.$this->tabname.' SET '.$update.' WHERE id='.$id;
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'done' in 'field list'' in D:\OpenServer\domains\mvc.dev\models\database.php:55 Stack trace: #0 D:\OpenServer\domains\mvc.dev\models\database.php(55): PDOStatement->execute() #1 D:\OpenServer\domains\mvc.dev\views\profile.php(47): DatabaseEdit->updateNew(Array, Array, 63) #2 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\mvc.dev\models\database.php on line 55

Comment: What are you passing to the function?

Comment: $fields = array('title','post');
            $values = array('done','done');
            $id = 63;
            $upd = new DatabaseEdit('posts');
            $upd->updateNew($fields,$values,$id);

Answer (score 0):

Use following syntax for updates

```
UPDATE `tablename`
SET `column1`='new column1 value', `column2`='new column2 value'
WHERE `somecolumn`='some value';
```